# xib auto resize mystery?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have two different projects - both have the same settings/build configurations (I went over everything.. couldn't find any difference) and they both contain a reference to the same XIB file - the XIB file is designed for iPhone 4

Here's the code I use for loading the nib:

```
CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
UnregScreen *screen = [[UnregScreen alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[screenControl_ pushScreen:screen]; // Adds the view to the root view
...


// Inside UnregScreen:initWithFrame:
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
NSArray *bundleObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"UnregScreen" owner:self options:nil];
for (id object in bundleObjects) {
    [self addSubview:object];
}
```

On project 1:
it works fine both on iPhone 4 AND iPhone 6.

On project 2: It works fine for iPhone 4, but on iPhone 6 it does not auto resize the width the of xib, so it looks like this (notice the white margin on the right):

[image]

I'm banging my head against the wall as EVERYTHING is the same. this is the SAME xib on BOTH projects - on project 1 it's fine, on project 2 it isn't.

Where should I look??

Comment: Are you rendering both projects in native iPhone 6 resolution? This could happen if you for instance add a launch screen to one project that makes the app run in native iPhone 6 resolution but the other project uses iPhone 5 scaled resolution.

Comment: @PeterSegerblom both projects use the same Images.xcassets folder

Comment: Are other views working correctly? It really looks like it's rendering in iPhone 5 resolution...

Comment: As mentioned in question this view works fine on project 1 but when I use the same code/file on project 2 it won't resize the view to fit to the screen. Where do I find the rendering settings?

Comment: I have just tested and if I take other views from project 1 and try to use them on project 2 - I see the same resizing problem - it won't resize the view to fit

Comment: I don't know.. i just know that when we added a Launch screen .xib to our project it started to render everything in native iPhone 6 resolution and then a lot of views looked like that. You are using auto layout I guess? You can add the launch screen under "targets->General->app icons and launch screens" section if you want to try. On your first project i mean so you can see if you get the same problem.

Comment: @PeterSegerblom I've double checked the launch screen setting and it seems like you were right - It now resizes the view and everything looks perfect! Type in your answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check "Targets->General->App Icons and launch Screens" if you specify a launch screen file the app will be rendered in native iPhone 6 resolution. While the other project is rendered in iPhone 5 scaled resolution.